# What's wrong with the command prompt?

Tags: xubuntu

Something's wrong with my ubuntu. The command prompt suddenly changes from `maixaolong@709-dl-server:~$` to something in the picture below. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Did you change your login shell (perhaps to `zsh`)?

Comment: @steeldriver, Oh yes, someone changed the login shell to zsh, how can I set it back to bash?

Comment: @karel That looks like PuTTY, which would have a shell through SSH.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change your login shell back to Bash, run:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash $USER
```

Then log out and log back in.